# Windows Phone 8- Page running in background

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm working on a Windows phone 8 app. I have a few story board animations running on my main page. When I navigate away from the main page these story boards keep on running, though they are not visible on the UI, but with a debugger attached I can see the story board events being triggered in my code behind file.

**The Question: Does Windows phone 8 keeps a page and its resources alive even after we navigate away from it? Do I need to explicitly destroy all the resources before moving away from the page.**

P.S. I'm not using any extra threads to run the story board.

Answer (score 0):

WP keeps alive the pages that are in your backstack.

That means if you're leaving your MainPage with a **forward** navigation to a new page (Page2), the Mainpage will remain alive. And you will go back to the previous instance of MainPage when pressing the back button. The Page2 instance will then be destroyed (unless you have leaks in your code).

Btw a best practice would be to stop storyboard on navigation, especially if you're doing some operations in the Completed event of the storyboard. This event can be called when the page is not in the visual tree and can lead to some crash.